# CMIS Workbench not able to access Custom Lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cmis

I am trying to access Document Libraries and List Libraries(Custom) through CMIS service in SharePoint. I am able to access all document libraries but I am not able to access List Libraries.

Workbench and Postman(where I am testing the connectivity) is showing **List with given name not found!**

This my first time working with CMIS service I am certainly confused where would have gone wrong.

Accessing URLs:
***http://site-site/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/d97c88ca-db12-481a-b8e2-87c9f351044f?getRepositoryInfo***

Any Idea why?

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot? Thanks :-)

Comment: Also, when you sniff network traffic with Wireshark (or equivalent), do you see the correct information coming out of SharePoint?

Comment: You wrote "*but List Libraries*". You mean "*but NOT List Libraries*", right?

Comment: Hi Nic! yes Im  not able to get list libraries.

Comment: I just only want to Know that CMIS producer in SP is supporting for List libraries or not.

Answer (score 1):

The document library is the **only** supported as a CMIS Repository in SharePoint.

**For more details, please check**

- [Configure Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) In SharePoint 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/10/25/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis/)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, Thank you for your reply. yes I am using correct GUID. Even I called getrepositories It is only listing down Site Assets, Documents and  Images not My Custom List which is already exists. Is this the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not support Lists Libraries with CMIS.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/content-management-interoperability-services-cmis-in-sharepoint